# How can I make a custom editor that creates/deletes game object clones around a given point

Tags: unity

I have been manually creating and deleting clones of my game objects that I arrange in a circle around a given point. Each of the objects is rotated making each object the same angle apart from the others as seen in the image below.

[image]

My objects range from 2 to 10. Doing this manually is very cumbersome, especially when changes have to made. How can I create a unity custom editor that allows me to specify a number of game object clones I want to create around a specified anchor point? Additionally, adjusting the number of clones should dynamically create/delete clones and reposition/rerotate them.

Comment: Do you mean to create the objects at runtime? You can create a script, where you give it the number of objects, then creates a circle and places everything around it.

Comment: @TomTsagk not at runtime. I would like  them to be visible in the scene view before runtime so I can make adjustments to them without having to run the game.

Answer (score 1):

Make an object and position at the center of your circle. If you already have an object with a custom script there, make an Inspector for it. If you don't have anything, make a script. It doesn't have to do anything. It might just hold data. A custom inspector just needs an script. Let's call them `CircleSpawn` and `CircleSpawnEditor`. CircleSpawn gets attached to the object at the center of the circle. It might look like this:

```
public class CircleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public float radius;
    public int numOfItems;
    public GameObject clonedObject;
    public List<GameObject> spawnedObjects;
}
```

CircleSpawnEditor needs to be saved to a folder called `Editor` and looks something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(CircleSpawn))]
public class CircleSpawnEditor : Editor
{

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var tar = (CircleSpawn)target;

        //set its values
        tar.radius = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Radius:", tar.radius);
        tar.numOfItems = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of Items:", tar.numOfItems);
        tar.clonedObject = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(tar.clonedObject,
                       typeof(GameObject), true);

        //Inspector button for creating the objects in the Editor
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
        {

            //clean up old objects
            if (tar.spawnedObjects != null)
            {
                foreach (var ob in tar.spawnedObjects)
                {
                    DestroyImmediate(ob);
                }
            }
            tar.spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

            float angleBetween = 360.0f / tar.numOfItems;
            float angle = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= tar.numOfItems; i++)
            {
                //for each object, find a rotation and position
                var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
                var localPos = rot * Vector3.forward * tar.radius;
                tar.spawnedObjects.Add(Instantiate(tar.clonedObject,
                    tar.transform.position + localPos, rot));
                angle += angleBetween;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it and the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: all the objects have the same x value and some seem to be scaled down on the y-axis. They are not created around the clonedObject as you suggest. I haven't been able to figure out what's causing this.

Comment: I just fixed a few minor compile errors, but I tested it in Unity and it works fine.

Comment: I just found the problem. My game is actually in 2d that's why I'm having the issues. How will your solution change for 2d as in the image I provided above?

Comment: I know this was not in the original question. How can I add a slider to rotate all the objects round the circle  at the same time?

Comment: For 2D, just rotate around z instead of y: `var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);`. For your other question, `EditorGUILayout` has a slider tool. You could have a change in the slider either rebuild the objects but with an angle offset (`float angle = sliderValue`), or you can have all the objects be assigned to the same parent at creation, and rotate the parent.

Comment: I tried `var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);` but it creates all the clones at position (0, 0, 0), only changing the rotation regardless of what the  `clonedObject` position is.

Comment: Oh yeah, change the next line as well: `var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius`

Comment: But for example I have `clonedObject` at position (-1, 2, 0) but all the clones are around (0, 0, 0). The clones are always created around (0, 0, 0) regardless of `clonedObject` position.

Comment: Still on this. Every object in `spawnedObjects` is cloned around position (0, 0, 0) regardless of `clonedObject`'s position.