# How can I set a property for the upper limit for another property's range

Tags: unity

I have two properties, I would like to set one property as the upper limit of another property, hence making the upper rely on a property. As below:

```
public int fullLength;

[Range(0, fullLength)]
public int segmentLength;
```

Is there a way to do this, possibly with a custom editor? If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: This is using DataAnnotations I assume?

Comment: @Slagmoth No, I'm not using DataAnnotations

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple, use `OnValidate()`:

```cs
public int fullLength;
public int segmentLength;

private void OnValidate() {
    if (segmentLength < 0) segmentLength = 0;
    else if (segmentLength > fullLength) segmentLength = fullLength;
}
```

This method is called (in editor only) whenever the script is loaded or a value is changed in the Inspector.

P.S.: You're not using properties here, you're using fields.

Comment: Note that this won't show a slider widget for varying `segmentLength` between zero and the max, the way the `[Range(0, ...)]` attribute used in the question normally would.

Comment: @DMGregory you're right, I don't think that the presence of a slider is of utter importance for OP - it could be implemented anyway, out the top of my head, by using an `Editor` inheriting script, in which the slider is created in the `OnIspectorGUI` method and assigned the top value by using a reference to the `fullLength` variable. But I don't know if such work is really needed, I mean it's just a graphic flavor in the end.